# Como puedo crear un metodo que consuma un endpoint de una api en c#

Tags: c#, api

Necesito implementar un metodo en c# en un proyecto Windows Forms para consumir un EndPoint de una API, tengo la especificacion pero nunca he trabajaod con aspis, tengo los siguientes datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me puede orientar para implementar esto por favor, muchas gracias.

Actualizacion: Agrego parte de mi código:

Clases:

Entidad pObjAlmacen que paso a la solicitud

```
public class pObjAlmacen
{
    public Almacen Almacen { get; set; }        
}
```

Entidad Almacen

```
public class Almacen
{
    public string CveAlmacen { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public string Encargado { get; set; }
    public string Ubicacion { get; set; }
    public List<RepuestoAlmacen> Rptos { get; set; }

    public Almacen()
    {
        Rptos = new List<RepuestoAlmacen>();
    }
}
```

Entidad Repuesto

```
public class Repuesto
{
    public string IdUnico { get; set; }
    public string NumParte { get; set; }
    public string UnidadM { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public decimal Cantidad { get; set; }
    public string Equipo { get; set; }
    public string Plan { get; set; }
    public string Parte { get; set; }
    public string Actividad { get; set; }
    public string CenCosto { get; set; }
    public string CodigoEqu { get; set; }
    public string ClasifEqu1 { get; set; }
    public string ClasifEqu2 { get; set; }
}
```

Respuesta de la solicitud

```
public class Respuesta
{
    public HttpStatusCode Status{ get; set; }
    public bool OperacionRealizada { get; set; }
    public string Mensaje { get; set; }
}
```

Funcion donde hago la solicitud:

```
public async Task<Respuesta> SetRepuestos(pObjAlmacen repuestos)
    {
        Respuesta respuesa = new Respuesta();
        string urlBase = "http://localhost:9745";
        string APIKey = "val1=SGYvMUQrUGNMQ";
        string endPoint = "/api/SetRptosAlm";

        try
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(repuestos);

            var content = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = await client.PostAsync(string.Format("{0}{1}?{2}", urlBase, endPoint, APIKey), content);
            
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                respuesa.Status = response.StatusCode;
                respuesa.OperacionRealizada = true;
                respuesa.Mensaje = "Operación exitosa";
            }
            else
            {
                respuesa.Status = response.StatusCode;
                respuesa.OperacionRealizada = false;
                respuesa.Mensaje = "Operacion NO realizada";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            respuesa.Status = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            respuesa.OperacionRealizada = false;
            respuesa.Mensaje = ex.Message;
        }

        return respuesa;
    }
```

Actualización 14/11/2023: Ya logré realizar la solicitud con éxito desde Postman, para ello pase el json como una cadena escapando las comillas dobles ("), ahora lo que no sé es como convertir mi objeto a cadena agregando el escapado, ¿tendrán alguna sugerencia para hacerlo?

Según yo esta línea de código haría es escapado y transformaria el objeto a una cadena con el formato correcto:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(repuestos);
```

Pero no se funciona, siempre me retorna un BadRequest.

Este es el json que puse como parametro en el Postman para concretar la solicitud:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usando el codigo que genera Postman si se realiza la solicitud con exito, pero pasando la cadena escapada:

```
            var options = new RestClientOptions(url)
            {
                MaxTimeout = -1,
            };
            var client = new RestClient(options);
            var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.Post);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            var body = @"""{\""Almacen\"":{\""CveAlmacen\"":\""1\"",\""Descripcion\"":\""Mantenimiento\"",\""Encargado\"":\""FaroManager\"",\""Ubicacion\"":\""Mantenimiento\"",\""Rptos\"":[{\""IdUnico\"":\""2866\"",\""NumParte\"":\""2-1862\"",\""Descripcion\"":\""BANDA STRAIGHT 1 PITCH BELTING 1/2 x 1 FLAT WIRE 10 CM ANCHO KVP HABASIT GROUP POLIPROPILENO BLANCO\"",\""UnidadM\"":\""PZ\"",\""CostoUni\"":\""475.5000\"",\""Existencia\"":\""1\"",\""Localizacion\"":\""\"",\""NivelMax\"":\""0\"",\""NivelMin\"":\""0\"",\""NivelOpt\"":\""0\"",\""Clasif1\"":\""Bandas y cuchillas\"",\""Clasif2\"":\""\"",\""Activo\"":\""1\""}]}}""";
            //var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(repuestos).ToString();
            request.AddStringBody(body, DataFormat.Json);
            RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
            string res = response.Content;
```

Pero si serializo el objeto con JsonConvert me retorna BadRequest.

Comment: (1) Crear una Clase que corresponda a la respuesta recibida, digamos que la clase se llamará `ValeRepuesto`, para crear esta clase puedes pegar el json en https://json2csharp.com/ .- (2) Para llamar la API haces : `HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var result = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<ValeRepuesto>("URL");`

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por contestar, segun lo que he investigado, esto que comentas seria para obtener (metodo GET) un objeto ValeRepuesto como respuesta, pero en este caso es para insertar (metodo POST) informacion (corrigeme si me equivoco), por lo que deberia de enviarle de alguna manera un objeto de tipo Vale con los campos que se detallan en la especificacion, pero no se como hacerlo, pareciera que debe ir en la url o algo asi, sabes como podria hacerlo? gracias de antemano

Comment: Ok, el punto (1) es el mismo sigues necesitando la clase `ValeRepuesto` o `Vale` (como quieras llamarle). Creas el objeto `var vale =new ValeRepuest() { ....}` y metes los datos necesarios y luego haces `var respuesta = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("url", vale);`

Comment: Ojo esto es con las ultimas versiones de .net  (creo que de la 5 en adelante), antes se hacia de otra manera

Comment: Por otro lado, esta pregunta no cumple los requisitos del sitio, motivo por el cual te respondo en los comentarios y no en una respuesta formal. Tu pregunta debería tener código, como mínimo la clase y el objeto con algunos valores de prueba seteado

Comment: Hola, gracias otra vez, haré una prueba con lo que me comentas y te digo si me funciona, el proyecto desde donde voy a consumir la API es WindowsForms con .NET Framework 4.6.1, creo que esta algo desactualizada.

Comment: Me perece que no está `PostAsJsonAsync` en esa versión y que solo está `PostAsync` y también creo que vas a necesitas alguna librería para parsear a JSON porque no viene incluida. Puedes probar con `System.Text.Json` que es la que se usa ahora, pero no se si es compatible hacia abajo o con la `newtonsoft` que es la que se usaba en esos tiempos

Comment: ` HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 StringContent json = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Vale));
 var respusta = await client.PostAsync("url", json);`

Comment: Hola de nuevo, he realizado algunas y pruebas y no logro hacer funcionar mi codigo, anexo parte de el: var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(repuestos);
var content = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync(string.Format("{0}{1}?{2}&{3}", urlBase, endPoint, APIKey, json), content); me arroaj un BadRequest, me podrán dar alguna sugerencia, por favor

Comment: Incluso estoy tratando de hacer la peticion con Postman pero tampoco logro concretar la peticion, selecciono el motodo POST, agrego los parametros val1 con su valor (API key) y un objeto json pObjAlmacen con el json pero me regresa Sattus 415 Unsupported Meida Type     "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
    "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "status": 415,
    "traceId": "00-c0759bb68530a9f3ecc10303dc8d91e8-cb37c82ff4dc6b5a-00"
}

Comment: porque mandas el json en la URL?

Comment: Creí que iba ahi, de igual manera ya lo queté y aun asi no se realiza la operacion, que estaré haciendo mal? var response = await client.PostAsync(string.Format("{0}{1}?{2}", urlBase, endPoint, APIKey), content);

Comment: la definicion (que es de otra url) no dice que el json va ahi.. es un post, el json va como data... tampoco entiendo porque lo estas pasando a string.. C# hace todas esas cosas por vos.. una vez que lo transformaste a json (innecesariamente, C# lo hace por vos) lo pasas y listo... revisaste la documentacion de PostAsync?

Comment: me corrijo.. si esta bien lo que viene hasta ahi de codigo, content es correcto... los otros valores, estan bien?? la URL que arma, esta bien???

Comment: igual, entiendes que el endpoint que apunta tu codigo es diferente al endpoint que muestras en tu imagen, no?

Comment: Una disculpa, por error copie la especificacion de otro Endpoint, ya agregue la especificacion correcta, la URL esta correcta, pero no logro concretar la solicitud., no se como enviar el objeto pObjAlmacen

Comment: Mi recomendación es que primero resuelvas en Postman, cuando te funcione ahí te pasas a C#. También te recomiendo contactes al soporte de esa API, es habitual que la documentación esté desactualizada.....además quien coloca `val1` como nombre de variable para el APIKEY

Comment: Solo me dicen que faltan los caracteres de escape “\” para la comillas y algunas comillas en algunos ítems y este ejemplo: {\"Almacen\":{\"CveAlmacen\":\"1\",\"Descripcion\":\"Mantenimiento\",\"Encargado\":\"FaroManager\",\"Ubicacion\":\"Mantenimiento\",\"Rptos\":[{\"IdUnico\":"2866\",\"NumParte\":\"2-1862\",\"Descripcion\":\"BANDA STRAIGHT POLIPROPILENO BLANCO\",\"UnidadM\":\"PZ\",\"CostoUni\":\"475.5000\",\"Existencia\":\"0.0000\",\"Localización\":\"\",\"NivelMax\":\"0\",\"NivelMin\":"\0\",\"NivelOpt\":\"0\",\"Clasif1\":\"Bandas y cuchillas\",\"Clasif2\":\"\",\"Activo\":\"1\"}]}}"

Comment: En el postman vas a body, luego (justo abajo) pones `raw` y en la misma linea más a la derecha `JSON` y ahí pones el json sin los `\` https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sYiZ.png

Comment: Me arroja este resultado: {
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-7b39ed473939bfc33bb1664331146728-2c7836051a50f87e-00",
    "errors": {
        "$": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."
        ],
        "pObjAlmacen": [
            "The pObjAlmacen field is required."
        ]
    }
}

Comment: Estoy poniendo este json: {"Almacen":{"CveAlmacen":"1","Descripcion":"Mantenimiento","Encargado":"FaroManager","Ubicacion":"Mantenimiento","Rptos":[{"IdUnico":"2866","NumParte":"2-1862","Descripcion":"BANDA STRAIGHT 1 PITCH BELTING 1/2 x 1 FLAT WIRE 10 CM ANCHO KVP HABASIT GROUP POLIPROPILENO BLANCO","UnidadM":"PZ","CostoUni":475.5000,"Existencia":0,"Localizacion":"A1","NivelMax":0,"NivelMin":0,"NivelOpt":0,"Clasif1":"Bandas y cuchillas","Clasif2":"N/A","Activo":1}]}}

Comment: Ya logré concretar la solicitud con éxito en Postman, para lograrlo coloque el json en fomato cadena escapando las comillas dobles("), ahora lo que no entiendo es como mandar eso en el código, según yo esta línea de código haría es escapado : var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(repuestos); pero al parecer no porque siempre me retorna un BadRequest, me podrán dar alguna sugerencia para pasar el objeto a una cadena?

Comment: Prueba lo siguiente: `var content = new StringContent("\"" + json + "\"", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/text");` (nota: el que hizo esa API está para pasarlo por la guillotina)

Comment: Coincido contigo jeje, hice lo que me comentaste y me retorna: "Unsupported Media Type".

Comment: cambia de `application/text` a `application/json`

Comment: Hice el cambio a application/json ahora retorna BadRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema son las comillas dobles que hay que agregar como literales. Vamos a crear una función de extensión para convertir un objeto en un string que contenga un JSON (lo más esotérico que he visto en el sitio)

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static string ToJsonString(this object obj)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        return "\"" + json.Replace("\"", "\\\"") + "\"";
    }
}
```

Luego en tú código pones

```
var client = new RestClient(options);
var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.Post);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");


//ACA EL CAMBIO
var body = repuestos.ToJsonString();


request.AddStringBody(body, DataFormat.Json);
RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
string res = response.Content;
```

Comment: Me funcionó a la perfección, muchas gracias por tu valioso apoyo, eres un crack. Gracias totales.

Comment: @Sixxhack Cuanto me alegro, pero que el asunto ya era personal

Comment: Si eso vi master, muchas gracias nuevamente por tu apoyo @Yussef, saludos!!!